# Перехват нажатия кнопки Режим Полета

Tags: android

Посоветуйте пжлст, нужно отслеживать когда нажималась кнопка выкл. 'Режим Полета' на андроид устройстве,
с чего лучше начать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319334/8389574